# How to convert to a character date into standard date format in R

Tags: r

I have a csv file (df) with dates as " Mar-97, Apr-97..." . After importing to r with read.csv and stringAsFactors = F, the class(dates) is character.

I have tried : df$dates <- as.Date(df$Dates , format = "%d-%b-%y") & as.Date(df$Dates , format = "%b-%y"). class is converted to Date but it shows NA values?

Comment: You need a day in order to have a date...

Answer (score 0):

you can try lubridate library:

```
 library(lubridate)
> parse_date_time("Mar-97", "m y")
[1] "1997-03-01 UTC"
```

and you can vectorize

```
df=c("Mar 17","Apr 17")
> parse_date_time(df, "m y")
[1] "2017-03-01 UTC" "2017-04-01 UTC"
```

Comment: . Thanks Antonio but the class(df$dates)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt". Doesnt work

Comment: after parse_date_time the class(df$dates) was
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt". Then I used as.Date(df$dates, format ="%Y-%m-%d"  and it worked ! Thanks